# background image added to a div in CSS is not showing up in localhost

Tags: html, css, localhost

So I added a background image to a div using CSS.

```css
.aboutUs {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  background-image: url(public/images/team.png);
  text-align: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 310px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

But when I am opening it in localhost, all the images (which are in HTML) are showing up but the  [div background is not showing up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxTDl.png)

in my console its giving me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKCgS.jpg)

A help would be highly appreciated guys!
#happyCoding! :D

Comment: Hi there. I saw the error. Tell me your folder structure real quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check which is the structure of your directory

```
folder
   \public
    \image
       team.png
   \sub-folder
    style.css

background-image: url(../public/team.png);


folder
   \public
    \image
       ..team.png
   ..style.css
   \sub-folder
    
background-image: url(public/image.png);

folder
   \public
    \image
       ..team.png

   \sub-folder
    \another-folder
       ..style.css  
background-image: url(../../public/image.png);
```

Comment: This was very useful! it worked!! Thank you for this :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this?

```
background-image: url(./images/team.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add background-color to your div and see if your style is working.

Comment: I did and it worked. I thought that maybe something is wrong with the image so I tried a different picture but still it didn't worked. :(

Comment: ok try to copy the image inside thesame folder where you have your html file and use internal style

Comment: copy the image in to the same directory of the html file and do inline style like dis <div style=" background-image: url(team.png);"></div>

Comment: I did that and it was working. I changed my URL and my image is now loading. Thank you for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

From the error it is clear that your image relative path is incorrect here.

```
background-image: url(public/images/team.png);
```

Check your folder structure and accordingly set your url.

Comment: Yeah, my file path was incorrect. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 0):

**Try this style.**

```
    background: url('../../../images/animated-strawberry-image-0052.gif') center center no-repeat no-repeat;        
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
```

check if your pic url is correct

Comment: Yeah my url was wrong :( ....Thank you for your help :D